# var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp() will work on HTTPS?

Tags: https, var, xmlhttprequest

This variable `var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp()` will it work with `HTTPS` or not if I integrate this variable to fetch data through `ajax`?

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` does works over both `http` and `https`. (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) still applies and `http://example.com` & `https://example.com` are considered as different origins.